# How to tweak the hue of an existing shader?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, shader-nodes

in a project i need to work with an existing shader group that output a shader data.

The entreprise pipeline does not authorized us to change the content of this nodegroup and there’s no hue adjustment slider available.

Is it possible in blender cycles to adjust the hue of a shader data (green noodle) without having any access to original the color input information? Maybe an add shader node could help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you were rendering on Eevee you could plug your shader group into a *Shader to RGB* node, then do any color correction you want, and plug that into the *Material output* or pass it through an *Emission Shader*.
Though, this is more of a hacky solution and isn't available on Cycles.

Perhaps you can make a copy of that node group and modify that instead?

Otherwise, maybe it's time to contact your enterprise.